# UINavigationController Push Segue - Strange animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have a UINavigationController which was created in Storyboards, and connected with push segues for each view controller. However, when I click "next" (which activates the push segue), then animation going forward is strange. (See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cFo9sUtBeM). Going back (Selecting the root controller of the UINavController in the UITabBarController) has the correct animation though. Any ideas why this could be?

**Edit**: the boxes in the video are added by me to protect client identity. The animation issue detailed is the slide animation which appears to come from the top right (or top left for the 'next' button).

Comment: You could get a better idea of what's going on by enabling slow animations in the simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that setting a different Prompt for the navigation bar on the second view controller causes this weird animation effect. After removing the prompt, the animation now works as expected.

Comment: navigationItem.prompt (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html)

Comment: never used that.  i always do self.title=@"Foo"; in the contained view controller and i get what i expect.  so it turns out you didn't have both a storyboard segue and some presentation code on the button?

Comment: I had both a prompt and a title (see video, there's a title covered by a white box as well as text above that - that text is the prompt). Nope, just removed the prompt from each view controller and all was well.

Comment: In iOS 7, animation issues for UINavigationController with prompt are much worse: http://www.openradar.me/16395801

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a navigation controller push *and* a modal transition.  If I had to wager, I'd guess you have a modal transition hooked up to the button in storyboard, and code in the action method for the button doing a `pushViewController:animated:` on `self.navigationController` - (either that or the other way around, with a push hooked up in storyboard).

If that's the case, start by commenting out any button action code (any target/selector you setup in code, or any IBAction you setup in storyboard for that button).

Answer (score 0):

I also recently had this problem using a Master Detail storyboard with an embedded Navigation Controller. The issue was fixed when I changed the Background of the View of the Detail screen from Default to a different color. I found it did not make any difference which color as long as it was not Default. I hope that this helps someone.